# Randomly cycle CSS gradients on page refresh?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to see if it's possible to randomly cycle CSS gradients on page reload.

I currently have the following CSS gradients defined that I'd like to use:

```
/* Purple */
.fp-hero {
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, #6e48aa 0%, #9d50bb 73%, #b176cc 100%);
}

/* Light Blue */
.fp-hero {
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, #1fa2ff 0%, #12d8fa 73%, #a6ffcb 100%);
}

/* Green */
.fp-hero {
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, #56ab2f 0%, #a8e063 73%, #dce356 100%);
}

/* Tangerine */
.fp-hero {
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, #db5041 0%, #ff7566 73%, #fe8a5b 100%);
}
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: So what you are looking for exactly?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear @Mr.Alien

Comment: @Don He wants to cycle the gradients, is he expecting to do it with CSS only? As I don't see any JS if he has tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you understand why what you have isn't working, but to explain. You're using the same selector each time and the same properties. So each subsequent selector is overwriting the last, so you'll always end with your "Tangerine".

What I would do is change those classes to include a second class name and then randomly add that color class name on page load. Doing it this way allows you to target multiple elements on the same page and have them match.

For example (keep hitting "Run Code Snippet" to see it cycle):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var colors = [
      "purple",
      "blue",
      "green",
      "orange"
    ];
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    $(".fp-hero").addClass(colors[randomIndex]);
});
```

```css
/* Purple */
.fp-hero.purple {
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, #6e48aa 0%, #9d50bb 73%, #b176cc 100%);
}

/* Light Blue */
.fp-hero.blue {
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, #1fa2ff 0%, #12d8fa 73%, #a6ffcb 100%);
}

/* Green */
.fp-hero.green {
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, #56ab2f 0%, #a8e063 73%, #dce356 100%);
}

/* Tangerine */
.fp-hero.orange {
    background: linear-gradient(20deg, #db5041 0%, #ff7566 73%, #fe8a5b 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fp-hero">
  This is my element
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Don,  I'll give this a test.  Sorry if my CSS snippet was unclear.  I do have the other gradient colours commented out on my live site so they aren't overwriting each other.

I was just unsure how to go about taking those exact gradients and cycling with via jQuery.

The suggestion of adding additional classes for the colors and using those as the variables makes sense.

Comment: Cool, I even made the javascript a bit easier from my original post, just need to add color strings to the array and it picks a random one from there.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks, I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point, you have 4 css classes with the same name `.fp-hero`. So the last one's (`/* Tangerine */`) background property overrides the previous ones.

If I understood you correctly, I would suggest giving them different names like `.fp-hero-purple, .fp-hero-light-blue` and so on. Then you can set your target elements css class with javascript and change to other classes when you want to.

If you don't want to use javascript have a look at keyframes: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp

Edit: Sorry I missed the "random" part, so keyframes won't work for randomness. I thought you just want to loop through different gradients.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the key frames? I don't see how they could lead to a random selection.

Comment: There is nothing random about @keyframes ([found that](https://codepen.io/beben-koben/pen/iCIna)). It just loops through the colors that's all

Comment: Sorry I missed the "random" part. Yes, with keyframes you can just loop through properties without randomness. Sorry for that.